# Create JSON with function and FOR loop

Tags: php, json

I am trying to create a json response using a for loop and a function but I can't seem to get it to work correctly.  How would this be done?

PHP

```
$count = 0;
foreach ($bookings as $booking){
$item = get_users_custom($user,$count);
$item[$count]['booking_id']=$booking->id;
$count++;
}
echo $item;


function get_users_custom($user,$count=0){
$feed[$count]['user_id']=$user->id; 
return $feed;
}
```

Comment: where is json??

Comment: Item is overwritten on each run in the for loop

Answer (score 1):

PHP json_encode() function converts a PHP value into a JSON value. For example, from a PHP array, it can create a JSON representation of that array.

```
$count = 0;
foreach ($bookings as $booking){
$item = get_users_custom($user,$count);
$item[$count]['booking_id']=$booking->id;
$count++;
}
echo json_encode($item);


function get_users_custom($user,$count=0){
$feed[$count]['user_id']=$user->id; 
return $feed;
}
```

Comment: Your $item will only hold the last booking. It's overwritten on each booking.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a simple php array and the convert it to JSON using **json_encode()**

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_php.asp